# importing modules in application, not package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a Python (Python3) application (not a package) and have some doubts about the correct directory structure. At the moment I have this:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    launch.py
    core/
        __init__.py
        some_core_class.py
        other_core_class.py
    gui/
        __init__.py
        some_gui_class.py
        other_gui_class.py
```

I want the application to be started with `python launch.py` from any place in my directory structure - of course with prepending the correct path to `launch.py`, e.g. `python myapps/myapp/launch.py`.

Inside my modules I use absolute imports, e.g. in `some_core_class.py` I write `from myapp.core.other_core_class import OtherCoreClass`. I use the same way in `launch.py`, e.g. `from myapp.core.some_core_class import SomeCoreClass`.

But then launching it for example directly from dir `myapp` by writing `python launch.py` results in `ImportError: No module named 'myapp'`. I found I could make it work by changing my import in `launch.py` to `from core.some_core_class import SomeCoreClass` but this does not seem to me as a correct absolute import and is inconsistent with imports in other files.

What is the best way to solve my issue? I would like to avoid adding `myapp` to `PATH` environment variable which would require manual edit by the user or an installer. How should I change my code or my imports to make the application launchable from anywhere? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found, I can solve it by prepending

```
import os
import sys
app_parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(app_parent_dir)
```

at the very beginning of my `launch.py`. But this is so ugly and feels like a hack. There must be a better way. Python should not be ugly. Awaiting for better answers...

Comment: Seems like no other answer was posted to this question so I assume this is the solution I will choose.